# How to pass value from react render method to componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

How can I pass a value from react render method to `componentDidMount` and using that value call a fetch method to populate the data.

In the following code you may see that I have two fetch method and first fetch save the data to `'items'` array and `'items2'` array is supposed to save some date using the `id` returned from the `render` method

```
import React from 'react';

class CustomPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          items: [],
          items2: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ items: data }));

        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/' + id) //How to get this id is from the render method
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ items2: data }));
    }
    render() {
            let id = this.state.items.items.id; //This id I need to pass to the componentDidMount 
        }
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                //Here i plan to render the page using the values from the second fetch method
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default CustomPage;
```

Comment: You can not call `componentDidMount`. Instead, use your function or `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: How is `this.state.items.items.id` set in first place?

Comment: Ok thanks @Antonio so should i use the second fetch inside componentDidUpdate

Comment: @NadirLaskar items.id is the json value set by the api returned by the first fetch method

Comment: then you would like to call second fetch after the response of the first API call, if you like to call the fetch as soon as you have the id

Comment: @Antonio I did call this.componentDidUpdate(id); from the render method and I did the second fetch in the componentDidUpdate. It is working but it calls the componentDidUpdate multiple times and badly affects the performance

Comment: I would still recommend splitting your component into two components, the second takes props from the first, if nothing return null, else display data

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass the `id` from the render, you can call the second fetch right after the first fetch response.

```
// Call second fetch after you get the response
const getPage = (id) => {
   fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/' + data.items.id)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ items2: data }));
}
```

Call the `getPage(id)` method from the logic you find the `id`

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => {
          this.setState({ items: data });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the update @Nadir I dont think it is possible as the data.items has multiple ids and i have an another logic to filter out the specific id I want. If I add those logic in the question my code my lengthy and might not be readable.

Comment: @LalasM are you dynamically selecting an id from the list of ids before making the second fetch call?

Comment: In that case, you should call the fetch right after you get the id you want to make fetch call with.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you are fetching an API in componentDidMount and setting some state as

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ items: data }));
}
```

When you setState it would automatically cause componentDidUpdate to be called, there you can make the second call as

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.items.items.id !== prevState.items.items.id) { // condition
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/${this.state.items.items.id}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ items2: data }));
  }
}
```

I am using this.state.items.items.id as you are proposing it would have the id
The condition here is required otherwise it would cause an infinite loop as the React doc says

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition

Hope it helps